# Is rxplot no longer rosrun-able in Fuerte?

Tags: ros, rxplot, ros-fuerte, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Electric and earlier it was possible to do

```
rosrun rxtools rxplot
```

.. more importantly, this means that in launch files I could do

```
<node pkg="rxtools" type="rxplot" name="my_plot" args="/some/topic" />
```

and so on. It looks like this is no longer possible in Fuerte; only rxconsole and rxloggerlevel seem to be rosrun-able now.

So is this intentional? If not I'll file a ticket. If so could someone suggest a workaround to allow rxplot to be launched from a launch file?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33251/is-rxplot-no-longer-rosrun-able-in-fuerte?/) by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2264 on 2012-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like a bug to me.

There seem to be several problems with the `rx` stack in Fuerte. Please file a ticket, I hope we can get them fixed quickly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-05-04**:
Thanks, ticketed: https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3953